# Unable to resolve module `scheduler/tracing` react native

Tags: javascript, android, npm, react-native

i get some error like this in react-native run-android process

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `scheduler/tracing` from `/Users/miftahali/projects/react/appscustomec/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js`: Module `scheduler/tracing` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

this my Environment

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.2
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4260U CPU @ 1.40GHz
      Memory: 38.67 MB / 4.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.0.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/node
      npm: 5.6.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 19, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27
        Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.3, 26.0.1, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1 
      react-native: ^0.57.8 => 0.57.8 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
```

How to resolve this ?, thanks

Comment: This exactly what i am getting for error.. but unfortunately no respond yet :(

Comment: ust try to remove node_module and try to re-install the node_module.

Answer (score 2):

This type of error comes due to dependency related issues. Just try to remove node_module and try to re-install the node_module.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you update this
In app.json, change sdkVersion to "33.0.0"
and package.json to 
//react-native to "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz"
//expo to "^33.0.0"
//react to "16.8.3" — (this exact version)
with these things

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "react-native": "^0.59.8", update your react to "react": "16.8.5".